# Creating my own webserver using a raspberry pi via LAMP stack

Tags: webserver, lamp

I am following this tutorial on the raspberry.org website https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress/

When I get to the last step to configure wordpress, instead of getting this page
[what it is suppose to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC9jq.png), I get this [php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBZn3.png).